# How to access every entry of CompressedSource in google cloud dataflow? And get Byte[] of each subfile

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a compressed file which is a gzip file composed of multiple text file on google storage. I need to access each subfile and do some operation like regular expression.
I can do the same thing on my local computer like this.

```
pubic static void untarFile( String filepath ) throw IOException {
  try {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filepath);
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    GzipCompressorInputStream gzIn = new GzipCompressorInputStream(in);
    TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzIn);
    TarArchiveEntry entry = null;
    while ((entry = (TarArchiveEntry) tarInput.getNextTarEntry() ) != null) {
    byte[] fileContent = new byte (int)entry.getSize() ];
    tarInput.read(fileContent, 0, fileContent.length);
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore, I can do some other operation on fileContent which is a byte[ ]. So I used [CompressedSource](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/CompressedSource.java) on google cloud dataflow and refer to its [test code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/CompressedSourceTest.java).It seems that I can only get every byte from file instead of whole byet[] of subfile, so  I am wondering if there is any solution for me to do this on google cloud dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

TextIO does not support this directly, but you can create a new subclass of [FileBasedSource](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSource.java) to do this.  You'll want to override isSplittable() to always return false, and then have readNextRecord() just read the entire file.